# why do I get more points by editing the same question twice?

Tags: discussion, editing, reputation

I edited [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481597/software-center-doesnt-work) twice. The first time I fixed the code layout. I didn't see the spelling mistakes, so I had to edit it twice.

Instead of getting only 2 points for the edit, I got 4. But it doesn't seem right, I mean I could keep leaving few errors to be fixed with each edit and keep getting points. I think I should get only 2 points, unless someone else edited it and I had to fix his edit. I would guess someone could cheat right now.

Comment: "I could keep leaving few errors to be fixed with each edit and keep getting points" - You think there ain't no mods on AU! :-D Its fine once but if it keeps happening the editor will be caught.

Comment: @Venki I won't do it and it's not about AU only, all I'm saying is that someone will find a smart way to cheat, that's assuming they didn't already

Comment: ok, agreeable... some moderator should answer this IMO.

Comment: You cannot get more than 1000 points that way - and when such a question gets deleted eventually you lose all rep gained for editing it - so the incentive for cheating is not very high :-)

Comment: @guntbert I know that, I have >1k on chess.SE and I noticed that I'm not getting editing points anymore. The incentive may not be high but still someone could easily pick some rep. 1k gives you good privileges on SE

Comment: I was unaware that this was even possible. I know that I have done similar things. (seeing something I missed and going back to fix it). It seems a pointless exercise to try to gain rep that way though. There is obviously no shortage of questions needing answers and appropriate tags. I've been working on eliminating the installation tag and correcting those as needed. (There are currently over 4600 unanswered questions tagged installation). I haven't noticed any privileges to speak of, just responsibilities. I'm probably missing them. Can you name a few?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the reviewers responsibility to prevent such types of cheating. Also, going through links I discovered that [the first edit was accepted by the original author](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/276980), and [next by the normal way](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/276984). This is the normal behavior of the system.

And as guntbert noticed, this is kinda dangerous to get points this way as all points gained this way will be gone if post is deleted. I think that most extra rep you can get this way is just 4-6. This is really small and unmeaningful amount comparing to points got by standard way. People who accept your edits are generally smart and someone will report that you cheat. Just examining your activity tab can reveal this type of incorrect behaviour.

So, I resume: you have nothing to worry about. System is protected.

Comment: But I heard of some better reputated (subscribed for longer time) members in chat, that these review queues are incredibly long. I think removing double-edits (instead of adding both edits to queue, the system should replace the first ones by the last and just restore the older edit if the newest gets declined) could shorten them up? Not sure how high the percentage of double edits is though, maybe 5%? Would this be worth the work?